# Calling startActivity with shared element transition from onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-animation, onactivityresult

**I'm calling within onActivityResult**

```
startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, imgv, imgv.transitionName).toBundle())
```

**What I expect to happen**
*activityB* to be started and displayed with a shared element transition

**What actually happens**
*activityB* is not started/displayed until minimizing the app and reopening it from recents (animation is also not displayed at this point). Without adding the scene transition it works per-usual and calling this from anywhere else in the code works as expected.

**I've tried**

- runOnUiThread .
- `postponeEnterTransition()` with
  `startPostponedEnterTransition()` in second activity.
- `finishAfterTransition()` this results in a flicker and then showing *activityB*, I don't want to finish *activityA* but just tried this.
- Using `onActivityReenter()` instead, I can't do this as it does not seem to be called when I `startActivityForResult()` in order to use google sign in.

I suspect it has something todo with a race condition with the animation framework

Comment: Did you try calling startActivity after some delay?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to trigger an activity transition while calling activity is not in resumed state and onActivityResult is probably called before onResume

Comment: The order of the lifecycle callbacks should be `onStart()`, then `onRestoreInstanceState()`, then `onActivityResult()`, and finally `onResume()`. Perhaps there's a problem with running shared element transitions in a pre-resumed state? Maybe you could record that you _want_ to start the new activity in `onActivityResult()`, and then check for it in `onResume()` and actually start the transition there?

Comment: @NezihYılmaz You are completely correct captain thanks. I tested and just used a flag as I see Ben P. suggested until I can figure out if there is perhaps a more elegant way and it works. If you submit as an answer i can mark it as correct.

Comment: @BenP. You both are correct thank you. I would love an explanation as to why calling it without the animation would still work, and if that too should actually be avoided or is seen as bad practise?

Comment: I don't think there's any problem starting an activity **without** a shared element transition from `onActivityResult()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onActivityResult()` is called between `onStart()` and `onResume()` for modern versions of the Android API. It sounds like there's a problem starting a new Activity *with a shared element transition* before your activity has resumed.

(I'm not sure why this problem exists. Perhaps another user can answer that.)

To work around this issue, I recommend saving information in `onActivityResult()` and then querying it in `onResume()`:

```
private boolean launchNextActivity = false;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (...) {
        this.launchNextActivity = true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (launchNextActivity) {
        launchNextActivity = false;
        // do the launch
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using androidx lifecycle, you can use the following code in your `onActivityResult`:

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
    val bundle = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this@MyActivity, imgv, imgv.transitionName).toBundle()
    startActivity(intent, bundle)
}
```

This will behave the same as the accepted answer.